# Como formatar coluna em percentual na geração de planilha com PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

Estou gerando uma planilha usando o PHPExcel e por uma necessidade preciso que algumas células da planilha sejam formatadas em porcentagem, tenho esse código que gera a planilha.

```
// MONTANDO A PLANILHA
$linha = 2;
foreach ($BuscaEvolucao as $RegEvolucao){
    
    $IdUnicoop = $RegEvolucao->IdUnicoop;
    
    // NOME DA UNIDADE
    $Unidade = "SELECT Nome FROM cadUnicoop WHERE IdUnicoop = ?";
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($Unidade);
    $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUnicoop, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();
    // RECUPERANDO UMA COLUNA
    $Unidade = $stm->fetchColumn();
    // FECHANDO A CONSULTA
    $stm->closeCursor(); 
    // RECUPERANDO INFORMAÇÃO
    $NomeUnidade = $Unidade;    
    
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$linha, $NomeUnidade);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->ConLav_Bom);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->MediaProdutividadeBom);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->ConLav_Regular);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->MediaProdutividadeRegular);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('F'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->ConLav_Ruim_Pessimo);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('G'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->MediaProdututivadePessimo);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->EstagioAPlantar);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('I'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->EstagioPlantado);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('J'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->EstagioEmergido);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('K'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->EstagioDesenvVeget);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('L'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->EstagioFlorescimento);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('M'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->EstagioEnchimento);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('N'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->EstagioMaturacao);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('O'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->EstagioColheita);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('P'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->EstagioColhido);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('Q'.$linha, $RegEvolucao->Produtividade);
    $linha++;
}
```

Tentei dessa forma:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$linha)->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray(array('code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00));
```

As células que tentei formatar é a B até a Q mas não deu certo.

Comment: O quê exatamente não deu certo na forma que tentou? Segundo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428767/formatting-a-cell-to-a-percentage-in-phpexcel), o que você tentou está certo, com alguns comentários dizendo para trocar `FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00` por `FORMAT_PERCENTAGE`.

Comment: Olá @Benilson, valeu pela dica, o formato está ficando dessa forma 9500%, o valor está sendo multiplicado por 100.

Comment: Então, essa formatação espera receber um valor 0.95 e não 95, é só você dividir o seus valores por 100 antes de aplicar a formatação.

Answer (score -1):

Supondo que seu celular é A1 ...

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray( 
        array( 
            'code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
        )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde,
tente algo assim:

```
<?php

    $n = "10,50";

    $ar = preg_split ("/\,/", $n);

    $tr = "";

    foreach ($ar as $value => $key){
       $tr .= "<tr>";
       $tr .=       "<td>{$key}</td>";
       $tr .=       "<td>={$key}*20%</td>"; //AQUI PODE COLOCAR FUNCAO
       $tr .=  "</tr>";
    }

    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=teste.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>N</td>
        <td>%</td>
    </tr>
    <?php echo $tr?>
</table>
```

Pode ser melhorado e deixar mais dinâmico e etc.
att.